# how to position divs in grid layout with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a grid layout with javascript but it doesn't work it doing some wired things it only create the first cell of the row and not the entire row.

here is the code:

```
<style>
body {
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

.imgCell {
    position: absolute;
    width: 84px;
    height: 84px;
    background: rgba(200, 50, 50, 1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.tdCellName {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>
<script>
function displayIMG() {
    var str = "";
    var m = 0;
    var j = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i <= GlobalImgList.length-1; i++) {

        m = m+1;
        var divsID = "flscell"+i;
        var Img = GlobalImgList[i];

        var posy = "10";
        var posx = parseFloat(Math.abs(10+110*i));

        //how many cells to count until breaking to a new row
        if(m%7 == 0) {
            j = j+1;
                var posx = "10";
                var posy = parseFloat(Math.abs(10+110*i));
            }

                str += "<div id=\""+divsID+"\" class=\"imgCell\" style=\"top: "+posy+"px; left: "+posx+"px; opacity: 1;\">";
                    str += "<div style=\"position: relative; top: 11px; left: 11px;\">";
                        str += "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>";
                        str += "<tr>";
                        str += "<td class=\"tdCellName\" align=\"center\">";
                        str += Img;
                        str += "</td>";
                        str += "</tr>";
                        str += "</table>";
                    str += "</div>";
                str += "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="main" style="position: absolute; top: 34px; left: 0px; width: 1879px; height: 1124px; padding: 20px; overflow: scroll;">
</div>
</body>
```

I'm lost here :( help me please :)

Comment: Make a link on fiddle

Comment: Any reason why your not using a CSS grid system like bootsrap or 960gs has

Comment: I want it to be pure js

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things you really don't want to be doing here:

Firstly you're actually using CSS to style the elements so either remove this and put all that style into the mark-up directly or consider using more CSS (such as styling for a table and make your life a little easier). You could for instance do exactly what you want with a table or CSS flex-box and output multiple rows of 7 columns that has 11px of padding around the images with much simple mark-up and a small bit appropriate styling in css in just a few simple lines.

That said, your JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= GlobalImgList.length-1; i++) {
```

instead, why not just use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < GlobalImgList.length; i++) {
```

you could just as easily check using

```
if( (i % 7) === 0 )
```

and not require the extra variable (and also the number of images per row wont be out by one as you actually seem to increment m to be 1 more than i inside each loop so it won't render like you expect anyway.)

You probably really wanted to start j at 0 rather than 1 (because you increment it inside you condition anyway)

```
var j = 1;    should really be var j = 0;
```

Talking of incrementing

```
if(m%7 == 0) {
   j = j+1;
   var posx = "10";
   var posy = parseFloat(Math.abs(10+110*i));
}
```

Did you really mean yo do this or did you intent to determine the y position based on the value of j, like this

```
if( (i % 7) === 0) {
   posx = 10;
   posy = parseFloat(Math.abs(10+110*j));
   j++;
}
```

because you seem to redefine the variables of xpos and ypos locally and then throw away the values (when you come back out of the braces) and you keep switching between numbers and strings.

You have ALWAYS wired ypos as "10" for every row because its inside the loop, not outside with str.

There is no need to use xpos and ypos as strings and then parse them into floats  to work out positions and then turn them back into string to concatenate your styling with "px" added - (just leave them both as numbers).

You can mix single and double quote in strings to make your life easier to concatenate string so instead of doing this

```
"<div id=\""+divsID+"\" class=\"imgCell\" style=\"top: "+posy+"px; left: "+posx+"px; opacity: 1;\">";
```

try this instead,

```
'<div id="'+divsID+'" class="imgCell" style="top:'+posy+'px; left: '+posx+'px; opacity:1;">';
```

If I understand your you code correctly then EACH cell in your row is in fact this colossal set of mark-up

```
<div id="" class="imgCell" style="top:posy; left:posx; opacity:1">
  <div style="position: relative; top: 11px; left: 11px;">
    <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdCellName" align="center">
        [Img]
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each item being a DIV inside a DIV with a TABLE inside that with a TR inside that with a single TD that hold the link to the image ...

Since you're using tables why not just render the whole thing as a table and give the table and just give the cell some padding of 11px. Or better still just get rid of the that and just put you image directly under the second div and apply style attribute to that div to set the spacing and positional effects you desire.

To make your life simple, just create a loop for the first two images and then DEBUG the code to see that you are A) getting the xpos and ypos value that you expect. B) that the string you get has all the DIVS in it with the right style attributes applied.

If you simplify the code and clean up the mark-up as suggested then this could be a quick visual check on a couple of elements